# How to check column value is member of another list-type column of the same tibble in R?

Tags: r, list, tibble

The tibble contains a list as a column(here the column named `Imgs`), and I want to check whether the values in another column(here `Img`) is member of this column(`Imgs`).

I tried with `mutate(In = ifelse(Img %in% Imgs[[1]], TRUE, FALSE))`, but they all checked with the first row of `Imgs`. As you can see, `Imgs` varies based on `Condition`.

[image: data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, we can use `mapply`/`Map`

```
df$In <- mapply(function(x, y) any(x %in% y), df$IMG, df$Imgs)
df
#  Condition IMG       Imgs    In
#1       CHR  14 13, 19, 14  TRUE
#2       CHR   2 13, 19, 14 FALSE
#3       CHR  13 13, 19, 14  TRUE
```

Or `map2_lgl` in `purrr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% mutate(In = map2_lgl(IMG,Imgs, ~any(.x %in% .y)))
```

Tested on this sample data :

```
df <- data.frame(Condition = rep("CHR", 3), IMG = c(14, 2, 13))
df$Imgs <- list(c(13, 19, 14))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, In := unlist(Map(`%in%`, IMG, Imgs))][]
#   Condition IMG     Imgs    In
#1:       CHR  14 13,19,14  TRUE
#2:       CHR   2 13,19,14 FALSE
#3:       CHR  13 13,19,14  TRUE
```